How to produce steel in space?
My steel producing company wants to move into space for reasons. They are commonly known for producing steel from iron ore with all the necessary steps in between. The main question is how they would adapt one of the steel production processes used on Earth, to be used in space.
In this world there are asteroids with:

High iron content (say >15%).
Carbon-rich ones.
And any other 'common asteroid materials' (if needed).

The company is eyeing a large asteroid to settle its first fabrication plant. This is mostly so that they can use the produced microgravity in the production process and as an early access point for materials.

The company will spend A LOT of time and money to set this up. They will hire whatever scientist they need.
The tech is slightly futuristic (say 50-ish years?). Anything theoretically plausible.

The company is trying to be the first in the market, with their eventual goal being; To move to further process steel, and eventually get into building spaceships.

Now the production process:
I imagine a floating, spinning sphere of molten ore. Asteroid pieces get added and molten into the sphere. The pieces are heated and molten through inductive heating of the metallic parts. Through spinning, buoyancy, melting points, and magneticity, materials are extracted from the sphere. The separated hot iron gets further worked into steel. Other materials may be cast into ingots, re-capturing the heat to direct back to the sphere.
Now, most of this is far-fetched. How do I turn this into a believable process of producing steel from raw iron, while using the unique resources/opportunities space offers?
I'd love to make use of microgravity, the lessened loss of heat (no atmosphere), and that I could do all of this 'out in the open'. I am willing to handwave getting everything in place, this question is solely about whether it would work if it got there.

I personally am of the opinion that this is a good question: the OP has a world in which there is in-space steel manufacturing and is seeking rationalization for a realistic/semi-realistic way that could work. I can see why this might be interpreted as story-based depending on how you look at the phrasing but I would urge against VTC in this case.

The main problem in space is how to get rid of waste heat. If you are on a moon or asteroid, dump heat in the "ground", if not it gets ticky. For how to separate metals from their alloys please, enjoy this video.

@FrogOfJuly would there be a way to re-use the heat instead? Heating up new ore with the heat from the refined products.

I need to disagree with @controlgroup. The idea isn't complete enough to be a [tag:review-my-idea] question, but it's a big enough project that it violates the [help/dont-ask] book rule. Review-My-Idea can't be used to develop an idea, so this needs to be broken down into pieces or it needs to be closed. Using the traditional process as a guide, are we only talking about the "steel making" step? If so, please [edit] your post to make that very clear. Thanks.

@vinzzz001 yes you can, but there is catch. High temperature heat is easier to get rid from. Radiation is very effective at high temperature. However, after you reused the heat, it dissipated and now you have it more spread. Your overall "heat" effectiveness is low(see heat engine), so the heat is in the machinery, electronics, people and everything else involved. This heat is low temperature and you can't properly radiate it away.  This is solved by evaporation coolers, that are used to remove "body grade" heat irl. But water is lost in the process and you need to replenish it.

This is a completely sensible science-based worldbuilding question. If this is off topic here then what's the point in this site at all?

Steel in space is unlikely to be produced the same way that it is on Earth as the conditions, raw materials, energy source and costs would be completely different in space. Perhaps a variant of the MOND process used on Earth for refining nickel could be used for refining iron from asteroids in space as iron also has similar carbonyl compounds and metallic iron is more likely to be found in asteroids (as opposed to iron oxide on Earth) so no need for reduction just separation and purification to get iron followed by addition of carbon and other elements depending on the type of steel required.

I dont really know how steel is manufactured IRL, so I had to do a little bit of research there to figure some stuff out. Some of my information could be wrong.
Resource hunting and logistics
I know that steel is just iron and carbon, so you need to obtain those 2 things. You have iron rich asteroids, and asteroids with carbon. I dont know if theyre close by where our station needs to be but if the station's asteroid is big enough and the asteroids small enough you could push the resource asteroids to get into orbit around your station's asteroid. If you cant get an asteroid into orbit around your station youll just have to get that resource asteroid in orbit around whatever your stations asteroid is orbiting, as close as you can to the station. That way you can use those resources more easily than if you had to mine at that asteroid and then go ALL the way back to the station. Just bring the mine to you. A little bit of delta V and a lot of time can move stuff around just fine.
You also want icy asteroids. You need water, or at least, oxygen, which you could get from water, from ice. Get Ice.
Utility of oxygen
You want oxygen because simply melting iron ore and adding carbon wont work. Your steel will be impure, and i want pure steel in my space ships. To prevent this, (pure) oxygen is blown through the molten iron which will react with impurities to make the molten iron more pure. This is a massive simplification of steel production, Here is more on the Basic oxygen process that im going off of.
Heat and power management
I originally had 2 paragraphs typed out and then realized a diagram would be easier. So I made one. Ill still provide some additional notes on some things where needed. Power and heat generation are tied together heavily, and thats why the diagram only shows heat, because really, theyre both energy, and in this case, energy that doesnt really leave the system easily, so we should try to redirect it elsewhere.

[Heat goes to water?] At extreme temperatures, water splits into oxygen and hydrogen (thermolysis, you could use electrolysis if energy is no problem). We need oxygen, a lot of it.
[carbon/hydrocarbon filtering for combustion?] Polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbons, which are... maybe existing abundantly or otherwise in space? According to some space nerds at MIT they could make up a good portion of the carbon that exists in space. Those PAHs, specifically pay attention to that hydrocarbon part. A combustion reaction is just a hydrocarbon and oxygen, which turns into CO2, water, and heat. More heat to vent, but also more heat to use for melting ice into h2 and o2, more water to be melted, and co2 which can be split back into carbon and oxygen using little power using these nanomaterials that we cant make much of yet but can make samples of.
Sure, we dont technically need the combustion part of this reaction, but it will help us liberate more carbon and heat from the system than we would without it. We get more carbon, and we get more heat to melt ice with, at the cost of some of our oxygen, which comes from ice. Its worth if you cant get enough carbon to make your desired amount of steel and you have some extra ice laying around. If youre short on ice, maybe want to hold off on it. Combustion isnt necessarily for generating energy, its for liberating more carbon, and trying to recycle as much as possbile.
This is a lot
Even assuming 100% efficiency, this is still going to have a lot of losses in the system, and require a lot of energy. Were definitely going to need to bring in a lot of asteroids, and we should probably invest in some solid power generation. And do something with that hydrogen... but, it is theoretically doable. You dont have to ship steel to space anymore, yippee!
Some questions still remain, like the hydrocarbon filtering, is the extra carbon we can liberate from the process worth the cost in splitting up and filtering carbon from hydrocarbon? Is combustion as a whole even worth it here, or should it just use a completely electricity-based heating system and skip the combustion? What power source (solar is a bad idea if you're far from the sun) do we use and how do we make it work here? These questions will remain unanswered for now, this is mostly an idea for how one could try it.

the hydrogen can easily be sold as fuel for space craft. its way cheaper to ship hydrogen form the asterid belt to almost anywere in space than it is from earth. Of course if you have fusion generators, hydrogen might be your energy source.

Frame challenge: Do actual research
If you really want it to be as science-based as possible, you need to find out either yourself or from existing sources, how to produce exactly steel in exactly space. You need to know what is your source material - if asteroids, it could be pure iron instead of FeO as it's on Earth due to atmosphere, whether that asteroid also has required metals to add to a certain type of steel (chrome-vanadium, anyone?), how does melted iron behave in microgravity, does it ever turn itself into something relatively solid, then somehow assemble all the required facilities up there in space, and then start experimenting - because if that company is the first to produce steel in space, it'll stumble upon a lot of obstacles, some of which are outlined in the other answer(s). Heat management could be a minor issue, as it could probably be diverted into heating iron to be put into a furnace, but other, including some weirder processes going on the micro-level (crystallization, cavities, thermal stress) might be the harder obstacle to overcome.
There are no existing processes of creating steel from asteroids in microgravity, and existing processes of making steel employ both gravity and carbon as a material to bind stray oxygen (which would still stay as a component in some types of steel, controlled by weight), which are not directly convertible to space-based. At least your facility would need carbon into their steel, which should be fed from elsewhere, processed as you don't have an easy way to turn asteroid-based carbon into pure form required for steel manufacturing, deployed and used while melting iron, then somehow distributed along the mass of melted metal with enough precision, etc etc.
As an alternative, you might not go deep enough for your story, declaring a steel factory as a something with known parts that should exist in any space-based facility, such as power generators, heat sinks, drills (that dig iron off the asteroid) etc, then put a shade on exact processes going inside it, essentially turning its core into a black box, which is fed iron and something extra, and outputs steel formed into required units (slabs, rolls, raw melted stuff, what you want here actually), although if you want your steel melted, you'll have to enter an entirely new and similarly deep hole regarding how does steel cool into what's usable. There was an article from a steel factory in Russian (this one, for example - there are a lot from the same source that depict various stages in steel production and how IT and ML helps them to do this better) regarding proper cooling of a steel slab, with a ton of nuances unknown to general public, which would be magnified at your space facility. So you can "just" say that it "works", hiding the exact details, as there are too many of them for such an entirely new process.

I see this as fundamentally a chemistry question, which I am not fully qualified to answer. I will attempt to describe some of the problems that you would need to solve, though.
Fluid transition
There are problems with having fluids 'out in the open' in vacuum. If there is no pressure, your material will not be liquid.
What will happen when you heat up your ore is that your material will transition from a solid and directly into a gas. To create a fluid you would need pressure in addition to heat, and the easiest way to generate pressure would be confinement, which would make it not 'out in the open'.
With iron it's even more complicated than, say, water:
See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_iron
What you're actually trying to do - Iron refinement
On earth, smelting the ore achieves separation of metal and slag due to gravity. The metal is usually heavier, and settles at the bottom. The slag, often silica, floats on top. In space your impurities could be different. Some of your impurities will be things that evaporate before your iron does, and you could use this fact to purify your iron somewhat, but if it is solid your material may not be ductile enough to allow such gas to escape.
There is something called Sintering, which could be a relevant procedure. I would encourage you to read about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintering
Possible solutions
If your ball of molten metal is big enough to have some sort of gravity, it could have an atmosphere of released gases, and enough pressure to be liquid. The problem is that all your heavy metals would be in the center of it. How do you get rid of the outer layer of slag? You're going to need to dump a whole lot of material, and it's not really so easy as to push it away when you are in space.
Maybe you would be better off purifying your metal by some other method which is tailored to whatever impurities you have, and then you could take your resulting powder or crystals or whathaveyou, and sinter it together after, and that way you could have your ball of glowing (but non-liquid) metal.

Frame challenge: microgravity is the biggest obstacle, whole process may not work in space.
In essence, we have tech to extract raw materials and produce steel in space right now. There is no need to go out of your way to figure it out. It's as simple as it sounds, and humanity works with steel for quite a while now, there aren't many secrets left there.
The other answers do look at various aspects of the steelmaking process, and  point out various requirements to make steel. The problem with them all is that they look at it from the POV of planetside process.
Some of them are not an issue in space, or can be resolved in other way, or simply do not apply.
But the possible dealbreaker is the microgravity. Steel is a composite, which means it requires combining several elements in correct proportions. Iron, carbon, nickel, manganese, chromium, molybdenum, vanadium, tungsten, as well as other elements necessary in the process, like oxygen, nitrogen, and so on.
Also, a lot of steel alloys require quenching.
Those literally would not work in space and/or microgravity.
You mentioned spinning heated in place - this will cause elements separation in distinct layers - iron and other elements are heavier and will drift to the outer layer of the "ball". Same with impurities, so in some ways it's great way to make high-quality steel, true, but up to a point - it will separate the elements into layers, after all.
You literally need gravity to combine the elements into steel, then do a plasticity processing (hammering or rolling; depending on use), then do the tempering (quenching, usually in oil nowadays). There is a reason why glues do not work in micro, why the miraculous "duct tape" is useless in those conditions, too, why so many activities normal on Earth require elaborate process/environment in micro.

It depends on the exact composition of your asteroids
The good news is, a lot of asteroids contain substantial amounts of pure (as in, not oxidized) metal. The most common type are chondrites, which are made of a mix of silicates and metals (mostly iron and nickel) with a grainy consistency.
So for energy efficiency I would say, skip the part of reducing oxides down to metal and just use the metal parts (except a small part that might contain other things you need, like the roundabout 1% carbon you need for steel).
For this, grind up your asteroids and throw them into a kind of centrifuge, sort out the silicates and keep the metal dust.
You asteroids will likely have different ratios of metal and impurities, so take your time, analyze each one, catalogue them and put the metal dust in different containers.
Now for the smelting, combine your inventory of asteroid powders such that you get as close as possible to the desired alloy.
Smelting problably also needs to be done in a kind centrifuge, but maybe you can get by with the microgravity of your base asteroid.
Some kinds of impurites you can separate by temperature (like lead), others by gravity, some might need chemical reactions (like blowing oxygen as another answer suggested).
The hope here is that by presorting you can keep the amount of refinement steps to a minimum.
Do not just throw everything you have in one smelter unless you want space-mystery-alloy or waste huge amounts of resources to get rid of all the things you added in the first place.

Rail gun based refinement and delivery process
Arguably the biggest problem you'll face is heat. Heat management in space is tough.
As Chuck points out, O2, carbon etc are all available, as are a bunch of other rarer elements we might to mix into our steel.
And we've got an extremely ready supply of heat - we can focus the sun's light for solar furnaces, considerably more easily than on earth. You could even have a massive array of solar mirrors close to the sun, carefully targeted to an asteroid you're currently working on.
The problem is heat dissipation. In theory, once we've got the steel molten, done all the processing to it, we'd need to then cool it.
But, instead, I'd envisage a massive magnetic array, drawing the steel through into essentially a makeshift railgun, which fires chunks of steel at a "catcher". We don't really need to cool this - radiative heat loss will cool it slowly as it travels. if we need a faster cooling for the crystalline structure of the steel, we'd thin the molten blob into thinner sheets.
Now, this has the excellent outcome that everyone is going to pay your space based steel refinery, who now has a solar array capable of carving "Bill Due" into the face of the moon, and an array of asteroid harvesting rail guns capable of firing chunks of molten steel.

you need a lot of large fragile mirrors at that distance from the sun, and you need a transparent containment vessel. just bringing a small nuclear reactor might be more cost effective.

Refining in Transit

An option you may want to consider is refining the asteroids ore in transit. Meaning that, instead of mining the asteroid, and moving the raw material to a refining facility, we will move the asteroid itself to a central facility.
This would at first seem inefficient to expend all the time fuel and effort to move the entire asteroid. However if we used the slag and waste material from the asteroid itself as fuel to move the useful portion and the transit time to separate the material as it travels.
The process would work as follows, and this is off the cuff and would need significant brain to hammer out the details.

refining module would rendezvous would the target asteroid  and stabilize its surface by encapsulating in, for lack of a better description, a giant bag, or some other method, a foam coating perhaps.... space glue?

Affix and secure itself to the asteroids surface and arrest unwanted rotation. This may require burrowing deep into the regolith to reach a solid surface, if there is one, which may be good or bad and is yet another question.

Begin collection of asteroid ore. (this in itself is a problem that needs to be addressed, but assuming this is solved) The refinery begins separating out "ore from slag"

Using rail guns, or perhaps mechanical means. Centrifugal gun? the slag is then thrown from the asteroid as a third law propellent to set it into motion toward it's ultimate destination.  The slag/fuel may need to be expelled in a manner that carries it away from populated lanes of travel, or aimed into an orbit that will take it into a gas giant, so as not to cause navigational hazards.


Using the waste material serves a dual purpose. A: it is free fuel. B: is reduces the mass that needs to be decelerated at the end of the process. [edit] A third benefit: Knowing waste heat in a vacuum is a problem. Loading the fuel with excess heat may be beneficial to this end.
Whether the propellent should be in the form of dust gravel or larger rocks should may be a consideration.
Speed is not a particularly high priority in this scenario, Think of a ULCC (Crude Oil Super Takers) which are some of the slowest vehicles in the ocean. Perhaps ~20mph top speeds. Filling the  production lane with a steady flow of ready to process ore is more the aim. Once the process has begun can be treated as an automated process.
To be clear I am sure the process may have issues, but none more daunting than any other real world solution. And  I give it points via rule of cool rules.

Galvanic Extraction
What is plenty in space is electricity- so if you coat a asteroid with epoxy foil, you could flood the asteroid with a corrosive substance using thehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrogalvanization
So all there is, is a robot, that coats the whole thing in a foilhull, pumps in a liquid and puts two electric poles to the end of things. Finally, you need a way to restore the accidity of whatever chemistry you are using. Which - can be done via the alchemist trickery of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemistry.

I now imagine the resource extractor robot being spider shaped.

Asteroid-spider-man
